# java how to count the sum of all digits in double variable

Tags: java

I've this code and I managed to count `77!` number. However I'm a bit confused how to count the sum of all digits in double variable ?

77!= 1.4518309202828584E113. And I can't use integer data types here. What should I do?

```
package org.kodejava.example.io;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Many {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(factorial(77))
    }

    public static double factorial(double n) {
        if (n == 0) return 1;
        return n * factorial(n-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: The phrase "sum of all digits in double variable" is meaningless.

Comment: 77! is approximately equal to 1.4518309202828584E113. Summing all the digits in 1.4518309202828584E113 will not give you the sum of the digits in 77!.

Comment: If you want to calculate the sum of the digits of `77!` you **cannot** do it by evaluating `77!` as a double and then summing the digits. The value you get when you evaluate `77!` as a double is **not** equal to `77!`. The `double` data type does not support enough precision to accurately represent `77!`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BigInteger` is the rescue
You can use BigInteger to handle such cases

```
BigInteger bigInteger1 = new BigInteger ("123456789");
BigInteger bigInteger2 = new BigInteger ("112334");
BigInteger bigIntResult = bigInteger1.multiply(bigInteger2); 
System.out.println("Result is  ==> " + bigIntResult);
```

Output:

```
Result is ==> 13868394935526
```

The above example will give you an idea on how to multiply two number. You can use your own logic to get your code working :)

**For addition**

```
BigInteger sum = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
for(int i = 2; i < 500; i++) {

        sum = sum.add(BigInteger.valueOf(i));

}
```

**For Factorial**

```
public static BigInteger factorial(BigInteger n) {
    BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;

    while (!n.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
        result = result.multiply(n);
        n = n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
    }

    return result;
}
```

**NOTE** BigInteger is immutable so you need to re-assign the value.

Comment: I wonder where did you find the isPrim(i) method, In my eclipse juno it doesn't work

Comment: friend.. isPrim() is not an inbuilt function. it was just an example.. okay let me change that.. and then try again

Answer (score 1):

How about using the [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) as below,

```
public static BigInteger factorial(BigInteger n) {
    {
        if (n.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0)
            return BigInteger.ONE;
        return n.multiply(factorial(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could translate the Double to a String and then convert every char to an int and sum these values. Like this:

```
double x = 102.4000909;
String number = String.valueOf(x);
int sum = 0;
for(char c : number.toCharArray())
   sum += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c));

System.out.println(sum);
```

You will need some ErrorHandling for the DecimalSeperator char I guess.

Comment: Don't use `new Double`, always use `Double.valueOf`!

Comment: @HectorLectorit doesn't work, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method parseInt(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (char)

Comment: Thanks, you need to convert the char to a string. I have edited my answer

Comment: @HectorLector Did you try? I got  this error: For input string: "." and I'm trying avoid it

Answer (score -1):

You should probably using a `Long` or `BigInteger` for you factorial calculation as you may be losing precision in your calculation using a double. You also do not need any fractional value which is the main use case for floating point numbers. Once you have an integer representation of your number it will make it much easier for you to sum the digits.

```
String num = String.valueOf(bigInt);
int sum = 0;
for ( Character i : num.toCharArray() ) {
    sum += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(i));
}
```

A different method of doing this would be-

```
long n = factorial(6);
int sum = 0;
while (n > 0) {
    int p = n % 10;
    sum += p;
    n = n / 10;
}
```